# External monitor bleeds over to second external monitor when widow is maximized

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display

I have a laptop with two DisplayPort adapters. Attached to the DisplayPort adapters are two external monitors which are the same brand and model. I find that when I maximize a window on my left external monitor it's right edge "bleeds" over to the right external monitor by about 2 pixels. This does not happen with the right external monitor. Anyone know why this would be happening?

EDIT: I am using Windows 10

Comment: If you use `prt screen` to make a screenshot of your entire desktop area, does it show too?

Comment: @ webworm Use the physical buttons on the monitor that's bleeding, it might be set there to a width that's wider than the actual resolution. Making it extend past its physical boundaries.